# Making a Histogram When Given Cumulative Relative Frequency

Tags: statistics

I need to make a histogram of the relative frequencies of a data set. I am given the CRF, but I am confused as to how to go from the CRF to the relative frequency. Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: perhaps posting all the actual info would help?

Comment: It would be kind, if you would give a reply.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X(i)$ be the i-th cummulative relative frequency and $r(i)$ the i-th relative frequency. The steps to calculate the $r(i)$´s are shown below:

```
     X(i)    r(i)

1    X(1)    r(1)=X(1)

2    X(2)    r(2)=X(2)-X(1)

3    X(3)    r(3)=X(3)-X(2)

4    X(4)    r(4)=X(4)-X(3)

...

n    X(n)    r(n)=X(n)-X(n-1)
```